# cannot connect to internet (b43 related problem)

Tags: 10.04, wireless, dell, internet

I recently came upon a Dell 1545 Inspiron laptop and decided to put a fresh install of 10.04 LTS.

At first I couldn't connect to the Internet because I did not install the driver for my wireless card (Broadcom 4312), but then I installed the first of the two drivers under the proprietary drivers list, it was the Broadcom b43 wireless driver.

While that was active, I could detect wireless networks but could not connect to a network. I then tried to switch to the other set of drivers, the STA set.

Now, I cannot even detect networks. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 12.04.  10.04 isn't supported any more.  If all you want is a Gnome Classic desktop, 12.04 has that.  When you are doing the install connect via a ethernet cable and install updates and 3rd party drivers.  This way out of the box it just works.  If that doesn't work let me know and we can debug further.

Comment: Isn't 10.04 an LTS version?

Comment: 10.04 is supported until April 2013 on the desktop.

Comment: but 12.04 is the new LTS and might have better support than the old LTS has.